# Dividing a circle's area into fourths via parallel lines

Tags: integration

My attempt at this solution involves first finding the equation of a half circle $x=\sqrt{(r^2-y^2)}$, $\int_0^mf(y)dy=\frac {\pi}{8r^2}$

Is there an easier solution? My attempt requires  $\int_{y1}^{y2}\sqrt{(r^2-y^2)}dy$ which I don't really know how to solve.

Comment: What are you want to calculate?

Comment: Take the unit semi-circle in standard position, let $O$ be the centre and $AB$ a line-segment parallel to the $x$-axis dividing the semi-circle into $2$ equal parts. Let $2\theta=\angle AOB$. You can find the area of the sector $AOB$ in terms of $\theta$, also the area of $\triangle AOB$. Now we get an unpleasant equation that can be solved numerically.

Answer (score 0):

If you whant to find the area of the circle using integrals you can use polar coordinates:
for $r=1$

> for the area of $x^2+y^2=1$ using double integral
>   $0\leq r\leq 1$

$x:=r\cos\theta,y:=r\sin\theta$
The Jacobian=r
$$4\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\int_{r=0}^{r=1}rdrd\theta=4\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\frac{1}{2}d \theta=2\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}=\pi$$